# To find the supremum and infimum of following subsets of real number

Tags: real-analysis

1.All numbers of the form $2^{-p} + 3^{-q} + 5^{-r}$ where p,q,r take on all positive integer values

2.{$x| (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) < 0$} where $a<b<c<d$

For $1$ As $p,q,r$ gets bigger and bigger elements of set are approaching zero but they never get to zero.  Also asp=q=r=1 value is $\frac{31}{30}$. So it seems zero is infimum and $\frac{31}{30}$ is supremum

For $2$/. This is a curve and we are taking part of curve which is below X Axis. So Supremum should exist at $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=0$ or $x=d$. I do not know about infimum.

Kindly help if this is incorrect

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to 1 is fine.  To have the product be negative, you need an odd number, here one or three, of the factors to be negative.  If $x$ is very large (greater than $d$)  all the factors will be positive.  You should find two intervals of $x$ that are in the set.

Comment: The intervals can be (a,b) or (b,c) or (c,d) or union of three

Comment: No, it is the union of only two of those.  Pay attention to $a \lt b \lt c \lt d$

Comment: It is then (x-a) union (x-d).

Comment: No, the ends of the intervals do not depend on $x$.  You need $x$ to be in one of two of the ones you mentioned above.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)) is a plot with $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$.  Over what intervals is the product negative?

Comment: Oh!! i intend to write (a,b) union ()c,d..

Comment: That is correct.  Now you need the inf and sup of that set

Comment: So sup is d and infimum is a

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: But can formal proofs be written for these questions or they are to be done just like that